# Using a cluster of Raspberry Pi 4 as a cluster for number crunching?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, cpu-architecture

So I am currently developing an algorithm in MATLAB that is computationally expensive but is parallel processing friendly. Given that, I have been using the parallel processing library but I am still falling short of my computation time goals.

I am currently running my algorithm on an Intel i7 8086k CPU (6 Core, 12 logical, @4.00GHz, turbo is 5GHz)

Here are my questions:

1. If I was to purchase, lets say 10 raspberry pi 4 SBCs (4 cores @1.5GHz), could I use my main desktop as the host and the PIs as the clients? (Let us assume I migrate my algorithm to C++ and run it in Ubuntu for now).

1a. If I was to go through with the build in question 1, will there be a significant upgrade in computation for the ~$500 spent?

1b. If I am not able to use my desktop as host (I believe this shouldn't be an issue), how many raspberry PIs would I need to equate to my current CPU or how many would I need to make it advantageous to work on a PI cluster vs my computer?

2. Is it possible to run Windows on the host computer and linux on the clients(Pis) so that I continue using MATLAB?

Thanks for your help, any other advise and recommendations are welcome

Comment: It's almost impossible to say, IMHO. It depends too much on how well your algorithm fits the RasPi instruction set and caches, on how much interprocess communication is necessary, how big your RAM and dataset are...

Answer (score 4):

Does your algorithm bottleneck on raw FMA / FLOPS throughput?  If so then a cluster of weak ARM cores is more trouble than it's worth.  I'd expect a used Zen2 machine, or maybe Haswell or Broadwell, could be good if you can find one cheaply.  (You'd have to look at core counts, clocks, and FLOPS/$.  And whether the problem would still not be memory bottlenecked on an older system with less memory bandwidth.)

If you bottleneck instead on cache misses from memory bandwidth or latency (e.g. cache-unfriendly data layout), there might possibly be something to gain from having more weaker CPUs each with their own memory controller and cache, even if those caches are smaller than your Intel.

Does Matlab use your GPU at all (e.g. via OpenCL)?  Your current CPU's peak `double` (FP64) throughput from the IA cores is 96 GFLOPS, but its integrated GPU is [capable of 115.2 GFLOPS](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/uhd_graphics/630).  Or for single-precision, 460.8 GFLOPS GPU vs. 192 GFLOPS from your x86 cores.  Again, theoretical max throughput, running 2x 256-bit SIMD FMA instructions per clock cycle per core on the CPU.

**Upgrading to a beefy GPU could be vastly more effective than a cluster of RPi4.**  e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS#Hardware_costs shows that cost per single-precision GFLOP in 2017 was about 5 cents, adding big GPUs to a cheapo CPU.  Or 79 cents per double-precision GFLOP.

If your problem is GPU-friendly but Matlab hasn't been using your GPU, look into that.  Maybe Matlab has options, or you could use OpenCL from C++.

> will there be a significant upgrade in computation for the ~$500 spent?

RPi4 model B [has a Broadcom BCM2711 SoC](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/processors.html#bcm2711).  The CPU is [Cortex-A72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A72).

Their cache hierachy 32 KB data + 48 KB instruction L1 cache per core. 1MB shared L2 cache.  That's weaker than your 4GHz i7 with 32k L1d + 256k L2 private per-core, and a shared 12MiB L3 cache.  But faster cores waste more cycles for the same absolute time waiting for a cache miss, and the ARM chips run their DRAM at a competitive DDR4-2400.

**RPi CPUs are not FP powerhouses.**  There's a large gap in the raw numbers, but with enough of them the throughput does add up.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS#FLOPs_per_cycle_for_various_processors shows that Cortex-A72 has peak FPU throughput of 2 `double` FLOPS per core per cycle, vs. 16 for Intel since Haswell, AMD since Zen2.

Dropping to single precision `float` improves x86 by a factor of 2, but A72 by a factor of 4.  Apparently their SIMD units have lower throughput for FP64 instructions, as well as half the work per SIMD vector.  (Some other ARM cores aren't extra slow for double, just the expected 2:1, like Cortex-A57 and A76.)

But all this is peak FLOPS throughput; coming close to that in real code is only achieved with well-tuned code with good computational intensity (lots of work each time the data is loaded into cache, and/or into registers).  e.g. a dense matrix multiply is the classic example: O(n^3) FPU work over O(n^2) data, in a way that makes cache-blocking possible.  Or Prime95 is another example.

**Still, a rough back of the envelope calculation, being generous and assuming sustained non-turbo clocks for the Coffee Lake.**  (All 6 cores busy running 2x 256-bit FMA instructions per clock makes a *lot* of heat.  That's literally what Prime95 does, so expect that level of power consumption if your code is that efficient.)

- 6 * 4GHz * 4 elements/vec * 2 vec/cycle = 48G FMAs / sec = 96 GFLOP/sec on the CFL
- 4 * 1.5GHz * 2 DP flops / clock = 12 GFLOP / sec per RPi.

With 5x RPi systems, that's 60 GFLOPS added to your existing 96 GFLOP.

Doesn't sound worth the trouble to manage 5 RPi systems for less than your existing total FP throughput.  But again, if your problem has the right kind of parallelism, a GPU can run it much more efficiently.  60 GFLOPS for 500$ is not a good deal compared to ~50$ per 60 GFLOP from a high-end (in 2017) video card.

The GPU in an RPi might have some compute capability, but almost certainly not worth it compared to slapping a 500$ discrete GPU into your existing machine if your code is CPU-friendly.

Or your problem might not scale with theoretical max FLOPS, but instead perhaps with cache bandwidth or some other factor.

> Is it possible to run Windows on the host computer and linux on the clients(Pis) so that I continue using MATLAB?

Zero clue; I'm only considering theoretical best case for efficient machine code running on these CPUs.

Comment: Awesome, this was very informative. I was looking into GPU processing since I already have a 1080ti. But since I am not very familiar with the two options (GPU and Cluster) I wanted to learn a little bit more about clusters. With all of this being said, I will be rewriting my algorithm for the GPU and see how many of my functions will work well there.